# Issue with Nuget package versions in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Net core application. I have created some class library project named Authorization and it has reference to

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.10.0" />
```

Then I have another class library project and I have reference to

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.2.3" />
```

Both these class library applications I have pushed to azure artifact and I am using it in current application. when I try to build the solution Its giving me below error

```
RepositoryLayer.csproj :
 error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Azure.Identity from 1.3.0 to 1.2.3. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
RepositoryLayer.csproj : 
     error NU1605:  RepositoryLayer -> Consume 1.1.46955 -> HttpClients 1.1.46955 -> 
     Authorisation 1.1.46955 -> Microsoft.Identity.Web 1.10.0 -> Azure.Identity (>= 1.3.0)
RepositoryLayer.csproj : 
     error NU1605:  RepositoryLayer -> Azure.Identity (>= 1.2.3)
```

already spent hours to identify this but could not able to understand the root cause. Can someone help me to identify this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try removing the reference to `Microsoft.Identity.Web`

Comment: Hi Hirasawa I need reference to that in my application.. May I know what could be the issue?

Comment: Microsoft.Identity.Web already contains a reference to Azure.Identity as one of its dependencies. So, just dont use both of these packages. Or install the same version.

Comment: Microsoft.Identity.Web is in one class library application(pushed as nuget) and Azure.Identity is in one class library(pushed as nuget). Now I am using both these application in my current api application and causing the issue. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Yup, install Azure.Identity version 1.3.0

Comment: In which application Hirasawa? I removed Azure.Identity and replaced with Azure.Identity.Web. No compilation errors but will this work?

Comment: Yeah, it should

Comment: You could have replaced Azure.Identity nuget package with the version I've specified

Comment: I replace with Azure.Identity version 1.3.0  but this dint work. Now I am changing from Azure.Identity version 1.3.0 to Microsoft.Identity.Web. Will this work?

Comment: No luck none of these worked for me

Answer (score 0):

3 steps:

**(1)** Use latest version

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Identity (`1.4.0`)

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Web (`1.12.0`)

(You should use .NET 5 SDK 5.0.6 with `Azure.Identity` `1.4.0` and `Microsoft.Identity.Web` `1.12.0` for ensuring compatibible)

**(2)** Clean Nuget cache, then get nuget package again.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders

[image]

You can/should delete all old thing inside the folder `packages` for clear all old stuff. I want make sure no corrupt files existing.

**(3)** Delete `bin`, `obj`, re-build project.

Let's share your result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I am using .Net core 3.1  so i should use azure.identity 1.3.0 right? what about microsoft.identity.web which version i should use? Let me clean and post my comments here Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, it supported by .NET Core 3.1 . See https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Identity/1.4.0 , choose section *Dependencies*.